# Mongoose saves empty object but object is not empty - Nodejs

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, csv, mongoose

I'm trying to parse a CSV file (which can contain multiple entries) and store the data directly into my mongoose DB. My code seems to be parsing the data correctly because when I debug and quickwatch the "entity" and "temp" variable, I see the data entries from the CSV. However, when I go to store the objects in the DB, I see empty objects w/ only an autogenerated ID.

**testCSVfile.csv**

```
author, ownerName, authorID, contactInfo, published, summary
jon doe, bob, 321, jondoe@gmail, 03/17, testing testing testing
```

**Here is my uploadCSV.js file**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const csvtojson = require("csvtojson");
const router = require("express").Router();
const bookModel= mongoose.model("Book");
const async = require('async');

csvtojson()
        .fromFile("testCSVfile.csv")
        .then(csvData => {
            async.eachSeries(csvData,(data,callback) => {
                  let entity = {
                    author: data.author,
                    ownerName: data.ownerName,
                    authorID: data.authorID,
                    contactInfo: data.contactInfo,
                    published: data.published,
                    summary: data.summary
                    };


                    bookModel.create({entity}, function(err)
                    {
                        if(err) return callback(err);
                        return callback(null);    
                    })
               },
                (err) => {
                     if(err) console.log(err); 
                     console.log("books are successfully imported!!!");
                     console.log(entity);
                });            
});
```

**Terminal Output**

```
[
[0]   {
[0]     author: 'jon doe',
[0]     ownerName: 'bob',
[0]     authorID: '123',
[0]     contactInfo: 'jondoe@gmail',
[0]     published: '03/17',
[0]     summary: 'testing testing testing',
[0]   }
```

As of now, the CSV file is local but eventually, it will be from a user that is uploading it from the frontend. Even though the entity variable has the right data, it isn't saving properly. If someone could give me some advice that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't see `projectModel` variable declaration !, you should be using `bookModel.create`

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Hi, good catch! That was a typo on my part. It actually is correct in the code.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? what's the value of `entity` can you print it inside `eachSeries`

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I'm not getting any errors when I print entity - the terminal output ^ shown above is what print outs.

Comment: Can you show how  `data` variable looks?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar do you mean what is inside the data variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined schema for your mongoose model, so it will let you insert anything in the database as the schema is empty.

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that was not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

**Create your mongoose schema for the model**

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition

```
const bookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    ownerName: String,
    // ........ rest of your model properties
});
const bookModel= mongoose.model("Book", bookSchema);
```

---

Change

```
bookModel.create({entity}, function(err)
```

to

```
bookModel.create(entity, function(err)
```

Comment: Doesn't the line "const bookModel= mongoose.model("Book");" create model from the schema? I think my main issue is that my object isn't empty but the saved object is.

Comment: @CharlieMasterson Please read https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict if the schema is not defined model will not insert anything in strict mode.

Comment: I added the code and it still stored the empty object into the DB

Comment: @CharlieMasterson change `bookModel.create(entity, function(err)`